# NodeJS Express API hosted on IIS over SSL returns Error: unable to verify the first certificate

Tags: node.js, iis, restify, iisnode

I have a NodeJS API application (Express 4) REST based hosted in IIS 8.5 (using iisnode). I have a few .net based and NodeJS clients who consume the REST APIs. The clients are able to perform GET and POST operations over HTTP but over SSL(HTTPS), it fails with the following error:

{ [Error: unable to verify the first certificate] code: 'UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE', body: {} }.

The NodeJS API application is hosted in IIS has a self signed certificate bound on PORT 443. I did test using Fiddler and performed a POST operations which appears to work fine however the client (NodeJS -using RESTIFY or .Net applications) are not able to perform POST over HTTPS

Answer (score 3):

If you add the following header to the request parameters, the module will ignore the permissions issue with the host certification.

```
rejectUnauthorized: false
```

For example...

```
request({
  url: url,
  rejectUnauthorized: false
})
```